# Split a multi-index dataframe in dataframes by column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataframe like the following:
[Multi-index dataframe by columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg4Ed.png)

I would like to get 3 dataframes named like each columns (compass, accel, gyro) with the timeindex untouched, and three columns each(df1, df2, df3).

I've tried 
`for index,row in df.iterrows():`
but couldnt really got it to work
And I was thinking in somenthing `stack()` and `unstack()` but don't really know how.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupby` allows you to split the DataFrame along a MultiIndex level with the same level_values. We will use `DataFrame.xs` to remove the grouping Index level, leaving you with only the columns you care about. Separate DataFrames are stored in a dictionary, keyed by the unique level-1 values of the original column MultiIndex.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (4, 9)),
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['df1', 'df2', 'df3'],
                                                      ['compass', 'gyro', 'accel']]))
#      df1                df2                df3           
#  compass gyro accel compass gyro accel compass gyro accel
#0       3    3     7       2    4     7       2    1     2
#1       1    1     4       5    1     1       5    2     8
#2       4    3     5       8    3     5       9    1     8
#3       4    5     7       2    6     7       3    2     9
```

#### Code

```
d = {idx: gp.xs(idx, level=1, axis=1) for idx,gp in df.groupby(level=1, axis=1)}
d['gyro']
#   df1  df2  df3
#0    3    4    1
#1    1    1    2
#2    3    3    1
#3    5    6    2
```

As such splits are readily available with a `groupby` you may not even need to store the separate DataFrames; you can manipulate each of them separately with `GroupBy.apply`.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to get them to separate csv files. I'll see if I can use the `groupby.apply`

Comment: @MrAce2C then in that case just do something like: `for idx,gp in df.groupby(level=1, axis=1): gp.xs(idx, level=1, axis=1).to_csv(f'{idx}.csv')` Instead of storing them in a dict, it will create 3 separate CSVs 'gyro.csv', 'accel.csv' and 'compass.csv'

Answer (score 1):

You can save the 3 first columns in a csv file, and repeat the process more 2 times to the others csv files...

You can select the 3 columns to your dataframe like this:

```
x = 0
data=pd.read_csv(file.csv, keep_default_na=False, skiprows=line_header, na_filter=False, usecols=[x,x+1,x+2])[[compass, accel, gyro]])
```

where x = your first column of the "big dataframe"

the usecols property is really useful in this case

You can read more about in: [Pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)